# Need explanation on this code involving TABLE type collection

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, types, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE multirowupdate AS
  TYPE t_record IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE;
  t_record record_t;
  BEGIN

    UPDATE employees
    SET salary = salary + 10
    RETURNING first_name, salary INTO record_t;

    FOR i IN 1..record_t.count
    LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(record_t(i).first_name);
      dbms_output.put_line(record_t(i).salary);
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Upon executing I am getting the **error:**

```
 Error(11,7): PLS-00201: identifier 'RECORD_T' must be declared
```

Why I am getting this error when I have clearly declared this is the declaration section.

I am using employees table in HR schema

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have got your declarations a bit mixed up.

You declare a type of t_record but then use that as the name of your variable?

I think what you probably wanted to do was:

```
create or replace procedure
MultiRowUpdate
as
type t_record is table of employees%rowtype;
-- This is not correct: t_record record_t;
record_t t_record;

begin

    update employees
    set salary=salary + 10
    returning first_name,salary
    into record_t;

for  I in 1..record_t.count 

    loop

      dbms_output.put_line(record_t(I).first_name);
      dbms_output.put_line(record_t(I).salary);

    end loop;

end;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks ! Now I see my mistake, I shouldn't have given similar name. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The right declaration of variable should look as follows:

```
record_t t_record;
```

With variable preceding it's type. But this correction lead you to another error:

```
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
```

It means that you are not allowed to mix PL/SQL and SQL context in types declarations. This problem is more complex to solve. To avoid duplication I will not post the solution here. Instead please read the explanation [in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844898/how-to-retrieve-multiple-rows-from-a-stored-function-with-oracle) which seems pretty same with your needs.